# multiple conditions in if statement using 'and'

Tags: python, if-statement

Problem statement :  IP addresses of the following forms are considered special local addresses: 10. * . * . * and 192.168. * . * . The stars can stand for any values from 0 to 255. Write a program that asks the user to enter an IP address and
prints out whether it is in one of these two forms

My code :

```
s=input('Enter the IP address :')
if s[0]==1 and s[1]==0 and s[2]=='.':
    print('It is a special IP address')
elif s[0]==1 and s[1]==9 and s[2]==2 and s[3]=='.' and s[4]==1 and s[5]==6 
and s[6]==8:
    print('It is a special IP address')
else:
    print('It is an ordinary IP address')
```

startwith() is a good option to solve this problem. However, i am unable to figure out why the above code always gives the output as 'It is an ordinary IP address' regardless of what the input is.

- Line(5) => and s[6]==8 is just and extension of elif statement.

Comment: You should always specify what language you are using. Why are you putting line 5 on a separate line? Also, don’t compare characters from a string to integers. In most languages (including Python, which I believe is what you have here), `9` is not the same as `"9"` or `'9'`.

Answer (score 1):

Subscripting a string will return a string not an `int`, like you're comparing them to. You should use string literals in your conditions:

```
s=input('Enter the IP address :')
if s[0]=='1' and s[1]=='0' and s[2]=='.':
    print('It is a special IP address')
elif s[0]=='1' and s[1]=='9' and s[2]=='2' and s[3]=='.' and s[4]=='1' and s[5]=='6' and s[6]=='8':
    print('It is a special IP address')
else:
    print('It is an ordinary IP address')
```